# QCustomPlot creates wrong curves on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qcustomplot

I'm drawing curves with QCustomPlot.
Now, on Windows as well as my Linux Machine, my code works fine.
Version from Ubuntu: [Here](http://webuser.uni-weimar.de/~gibo7890/lfm/verison_ubuntu.png) (Windows looks identical)
Now the version from my colleagues machine: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2cLx.jpg)
My colleague is running Linux MINT.

On my colleague’s Linux machine, all of a sudden, it does not any more.
The lines become all spike, the green plot becomes one huge spike, the red line turns into a flat line.

The code is pretty straight forward and looks like this:

```
vxf::Mode currentMode = readModes->modes[j];
QCPCurve *xCurve = new QCPCurve(current->xAxis,current->yAxis);
xCurve->setPen(p);
current->addPlottable(xCurve);
xCurve->setName("X-Curve");
QVector<double> dataX =  QVector<double>::fromStdVector(readModes->stations);
QVector<double> xValues = QVector<double>::fromStdVector(currentMode.x);
xCurve->setData(dataX, xValues);
```

(Modes is the data I'm plotting. Each of those windows is one mode.)
(current is a pointer to the plot I'm working on)
(Stations is something from within the mode, it is basically the stations of the x axis at which I have data, the currentMode.x is the data I'm plotting at those places. It might be a bit confusing as to how I use xvalues as y-value for the plot, but that's correct. I'm basically plotting x, y, and z values over time, and stations, or dataX, is my timesteps.)

This goes on three times for each of the three curves that would be in the picture...

Comment: It would be great if you can show us your code.

Comment: I've added the code of how I create one curve. I also was able to get a screenshot of how the broken version looks.